# Is this foreign call some kind of scam and what kind is it?

Tags: phone, scam

Every few days I get a call on my mobile phone from a number like `370 621 65748`, which seems to be a Lithuanian number, but it only rings once and then disconnects. It happens enough to seem intentional, but since they don't even wait until I answer, it's not clear what possible gain could be had.

Is this a known scam or attack vector? Could they be calling numbers at random and probing for vulnerability in some way even without me answering?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look up that number on Google you will see that people complain that the phone only rings once, so that single ring does not happen only by chance. You can find complaints posted months or years ago, so it's not a new type of scam. And if you google "phone scam one ring" you will find lots of results, because apparently this scam has also been in the news recently. Here's a couple of links, and one is from the FCC (Federal Communications Commission) that apparently issued a warning on May 3rd:

https://www.fcc.gov/consumers/guides/one-ring-phone-scam
https://gizmodo.com/beware-the-one-ring-robocall-scam-1834578615

It's all about getting you to call back. You see the missed call, you call back, and you end up paying a lot of money because of a special toll or a call to a foreign country. Apparently the scammers have a way to get a percentage of what you end up paying in the bill, or this wouldn't make sense.

Comment: Wow, that totally explains it. Thanks. Why do there have to be terrible people?

Comment: because of money :)